Vue computed prop change not being reflected in component if value references same object
example store:
const trigger = ref(true);
const prop = computed(() => {
  trigger.value;
  console.log('comp prop run'); // works!
  return some_big_object;
});

const doChange = () => {
   some_big_object[5000].text = 'abc';
   trigger.value = !trigger.value;
}

 return { prop, doChange }

in component if I call store.doChange, the computed function runs, but the component still displays the previous value (no updated)
if I change the return in computed function to  return {... some_big_object}; then it updates everywhere!
It appears to be because Vue does some check for the value, if it has the same reference as the prev value, it will not re-render it...
Is there some other way around this? I'd like to avoid creating a copy of a large object.

You can watch the trigger and update the component manually:
VUE SFC PLAYGROUND
import {defineStore} from 'pinia';
import {ref,computed} from 'vue';

const some_big_object = {5000:{}};

export const useUserStore = defineStore('user', () => {

const trigger = ref(true);

const doChange = () => {
   some_big_object[5000].text = 'abc';
   trigger.value = !trigger.value;
}

 return { some_big_object, doChange, trigger }

})

<script setup>

  import { createPinia, storeToRefs} from 'pinia'
  import { useUserStore } from './store'
  import {getCurrentInstance, watch } from 'vue';

  const pinia = createPinia()
    const self = getCurrentInstance();
  self.appContext.app.use(pinia)
  const store = useUserStore();
  watch(() => store.trigger, () => {
    self.ctx.$forceUpdate();
  });
</script>

<template>
    <div>{{  store.some_big_object }}</div>
    <button @click="store.doChange">do change</button>
</template>

Or you can insert the trigger into the template
VUE SFC PLAYGROUND
<script setup>

  import { createPinia, storeToRefs} from 'pinia'
  import { useUserStore } from './store'
  import {getCurrentInstance, watch } from 'vue';

  const pinia = createPinia()
    const self = getCurrentInstance();
  self.appContext.app.use(pinia)
  const store = useUserStore();

</script>

<template>
    <div>{{  (store.trigger, store.some_big_object) }}</div>
    <button @click="store.doChange">do change</button>
</template>

Or you can use the trigger as a key to re-render the part where the big object is used:
VUE SFC PLAYGROUND
<script setup>

  import { createPinia, storeToRefs} from 'pinia'
  import { useUserStore } from './store'
  import {getCurrentInstance, watch } from 'vue';

  const pinia = createPinia()
    const self = getCurrentInstance();
  self.appContext.app.use(pinia)
  const store = useUserStore();

</script>

<template>
    <div :key="store.trigger">{{ store.some_big_object }}</div>
    <button @click="store.doChange">do change</button>
</template>


computed() should calculate something, and in your case it just returns an object. In the example doChange you mentioned, changes some_big_object[5000], so calculate this property.
You can also return some_big_object from the store if you need it:
/* store.ts */
import { ref, computed } from 'vue'

export const useStore = () => {

  const trigger = ref(true);
  const some_big_object = ref<any>({
    666: { text: 'evil' },
    5000:{}
  });

  const prop = computed(() => {
    console.log('comp prop run'); // works!
    return some_big_object.value[5000];
  });

  const doChange = () => {
    trigger.value = !trigger.value;
    if(!some_big_object.value[5000].text) {
      some_big_object.value[5000].text = 'abs';
      return;
    }
    some_big_object.value[5000].text = some_big_object.value[5000].text.split('').reverse().join('');
    
  }

  return { prop, doChange, trigger, some_big_object }
}


/* App.vue */
<script setup>
import { useStore } from './store.ts';

const { prop, doChange, trigger, some_big_object } = useStore();
</script>

<template>
  prop: {{ prop }}<br>
  trigger: {{ trigger }}<br>
  <button @click="doChange">doChange</button><br>
  {{ some_big_object }}
</template>


Vue SFC Playground

it deep watches the object, not what the OP might want in the first place

@AlexanderNenashev What are you talking about? In my example, I also return from store the same some_big_object that is changed by doChange. Calculating it again some_big_object in computed makes no sense. Perhaps the question itself is posed incorrectly, because there are no details of what needs to be achieved.
